# ERROR Cannot read property 'matches' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, validation

I have to check validation for form input, this is my code for that

```
//onSave is a button save 
const onSave = (event) => {
    const invalid = [];
    ["name", "description", "category"].forEach(key => {
      if (key.value.matches("/[0-9]+/)")) {
        invalid.push(key);
        alert("Not allow number here");
      }
    });
    if (values.name.trim() === "") {
      invalid.push("name");
      alert("Please not left blank form");
    } else {
      createProductRequest(values, imageAsFile);
    }
  };
```

And this is what set values for that field

```
const [values, setValues] = useState({
    image: "",
    name: "",
    price: 0,
    description: "",
    categoty: "",
  });
```

But after I try to enter in my form input is number I got this error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'matches' of undefined`
```

```
  <Form.Group controlId="name">
          <Form.Label>Name</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control
            type="text"
            placeholder="Enter product name"
            value={values.name}
            name="name"
            onChange={handleInputChange}
          >
          </Form.Control>
        </Form.Group>
```

The form for description and category is the same

Can anyone explain to me why please, I do not know where I am wrong?

Comment: Looks like `key` is a `string` and the method name is `match`, so perhaps try `key.match(...)`? Also, you're not using the `event.target.value` anywhere in your code, perhaps that's what you wanted to do instead?

Comment: String doesn't have a property `value`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked at your previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63686930/how-to-add-validation-in-product-add-form-c-react-component) to get why you wrote the `onSave` function like this

In your react app you have a state like this

```
const [values, setValues] = useState({
    image: "",
    name: "",
    price: 0,
    description: "",
    categoty: "",
  });
```

To access these values in the `onSave` function your `forEach` loop should be changed to

```
["name", "description", "category"].forEach(key => {
  const value = (typeof values[key] === 'number')
    ? values[key].toString()
    : values[key];

  if (value.match(/[0-9]+/)) {
    invalid.push(key);
    alert("Not allow number here");
  }
});
```

And to stop pushing if there are any errors, your `onSave` function should be like:

```
const onSave = (event) => {
  const invalid = [];

  ["name", "description", "category"].forEach(key => {
    const value = (typeof values[key] === 'number')
      ? values[key].toString()
      : values[key];

    if (value.match(/[0-9]+/)) {
      invalid.push(key);
      alert("Not allow number here");
    }
  });

  if (values.name.trim() === "") {
    invalid.push("name");
    alert("Please not left blank form");
  }

  // Only push to firebase when there are no errors
  if (invalid.length === 0) {
    createProductRequest(values, imageAsFile);
  }
};
```

Comment: `matches` is not the name of the method, it's `match`

Comment: Is also wrong for me `Uncaught TypeError: values[key].matches is not a function`

Comment: @goto1 You are right, I just copied the code from the question and didn't check the method

Comment: @Kite Check the updated answer. As @goto1 mentioned: the method is `match` not `matches`

Comment: I am very thank you for your help, but I do not know why it still cannot work for me. I would like these field name, description field only allow text not number

Comment: @Kite I got it. You if statement was completely wrong. it should be like this `if (values[key].match(/[0-9]+/))`. `matches` was wrong and the regular expression was also wrong. Check the updated answer

Comment: Thank you @akram-adel, but I wonder why I entered number it still allows me to successfully push to Firebase without error that I shouldn't enter number in this field

Comment: Yes, I was about to comment that :). If your user enters an input that is completely numbers this will cause an error because numbers don't have a `match` method. that is why I added a checker before the `if match` statement to convert the value to string if it was a number

Comment: I am sorry if I do not understand. But I want user they just can add that field only text not number if they enter the number on that field it will send a message on alert that these fields it just allow text

Comment: Yes, I know. That is why I added a checker. Check the updated answer to get what I mean. see `Const value ...`: this will make sure that the function will catch when users enter only numbers

Comment: Thank you so much, I understood. But When the alert finished I pressed the ok button it still pushed to Firebase, how to prevent it from pushing to Firebase. Excepted, they are not in the fault, the push is allowed

Comment: Yes, you can check if the `invalid` array has any values by using `if invalid.length !== 0`. if yes then you stop pushing to firebase. Also, you might want to clear the invalid array with every new `onSave` call otherwise you will keep adding errors to the array and it will top pushing to Firebase forever. I will update the answer to give implement this part

Comment: Thank you so much, I hope to see your answer for this section.

Comment: I saw it, thank you so much. But how can I add that error message bellow in each field they have the wrong enter. Not alert message show. I Mean I would like to add an error is in the form group of the user input

Comment: Check this [section](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/forms/#forms-validation) in react-bootstrap documentation

Comment: @Kite Does the answer solve your problem? If yes, please mark it as the correct answer. I will be helpful for someone facing similar issue